# How to wrap a very long string that uses format specifiers/placeholders?

Tags: python

I know you'll be itching to mark this as a duplicate but the difference is I'm using a format placeholder.

original line

```
print(f"There are {rangeSegment} numbers between {rangeStart} and {rangeEnd} inclusively blah blah blah.")
```

Using the accepted PEP8 suggestion and the accepted answer on StackOverflow suggests using implied concatenation but this produces output with a tabbed character.

```
print(f"There are {rangeSegment} numbers between {rangeStart} and " \
    "{rangeEnd} inclusively.")
```

output

```
There are 10 numbers between 1 and     10 inclusively.
```

and attempting to split over multiple quotes breaks the string formatting.

```
print(f"There are {rangeSegment} numbers between {rangeStart} and" \
    "{rangeEnd} inclusively.")
```

output

```
There are 10 numbers between 1 and {rangeEnd} inclusively.
```

Comment: Just put the f prefix on both string literals.  Can not reproduce the tab character appearing /  voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print(f"There are {rangeSegment} numbers between {rangeStart} and " \
          f"{rangeEnd} inclusively.")
```

You need to put `f` for both stings.

Answer (score 1):

You have most of it working. All you need to do is to use `f` before every line in your print statement.

```
rangeSegment = 20
rangeStart = 2
rangeEnd = 15

print(f"There are {rangeSegment} numbers between {rangeStart} and " \
      f"{rangeEnd} inclusively.") \
      f" I am going to have another line here {rangeStart} and {rangeEnd}." \
      f" One last line just to show that i can print more lines.")
```

The above statement will print the following:

```
There are 20 numbers between 2 and 15 inclusively. I am going to have another line here 30 and 40. One last line just to show that i can print more lines.
```

Note that if you want to break the line in between, then you have to use `\n` where ever you think you want to break.

For example, if your print statement was as follows:

```
print(f"There are {rangeSegment} numbers between {rangeStart} and " \
    f"{rangeEnd} inclusively.\n"  \
    f"I am going to have another line here {rangeStart} and {rangeEnd}\n" \
    f"One last line just to show that i can print more lines")
```

Then, your output will be as follows. The `\n` will create the new line.

```
There are 20 numbers between 30 and 40 inclusively.
I am going to have another line here 30 and 40
One last line just to show that i can print more lines
```

Answer (score -2):

add \n in the string from where you want to start the next line